# What is the meaning of "right proper" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "right proper" in :

> When my motivation drops and I don’t have an interesting project,
>   well, I become right proper sick and tired of it all

I have tried to Google it but still not understand it.

Hope someone could explain for me. Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: It's a relatively uncommon *repetition* (both ***right*** and ***proper*** are "intensifiers") intended to convey ***additional emphasis***. A much coarser (but also much more common, I'm sure) illustration would be *I become **really fucking** sick and tired*. Again, both highlighted terms are intensifiers, either of which could be used on its own - but that one doesn't have the same strong implication of "rustic / uneducated speaker" associated with ***right proper*** as used together here.

Answer (score 2):

In this context "right proper" is a colloquialism that can be taken to mean "very" or "really/truly/actually"; it is used for emphasis.

This colloquialism (whose components are also often heard separately as just "right" or "proper") is very common in the Northern/Upper Midlands regions of England. The two components mean roughly the same thing (inasmuch as the words in their proper/formal usage mean roughly the same thing, i.e. "correct"), and in some regions you may hear only one of them (e.g., where I'm from, we'd often say "proper", but would never use "right" in such contexts - to my ear, using "right" and "proper" together like this actually sounds a bit redundant).

Comment: Yours is better, deleted mine!

Comment: Thanks for your clearly answer ^_^